# How tall was the average Italian Roman in the late Republic/early Imperial period?

Tags: ancient-rome

I've seen word of a study using bodies found from around 500 BC to 500 AD that gave average heights for women about 155 cm and men 165 cm, but this seems to me to be a wide range of time and area. By the Fall of the Republic the Imperial holdings were about as wide as they ever would be, and it seems likely that a Germanic tribesman in Allemania would have a different diet/lifestyle than the farmers and city dwellers of Rome or Tuscany.
During the Late Republic/Early Imperial period, as war raged across Italy and the wide expanses of the Empire, how did the inhabitants of the "heart" of the Empire, which logically would be able to benefit from the bounties of the lands under their control, fare in height?

Comment: Please cite the study you've seen; history without sources is like physics without units.  Does [libdsnet](https://lisbdnet.com/how-tall-were-ancient-romans) help?  What sources have you tried already?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the area of the Roman Empire was 2,750,000 squae kilometers in 25 BC, 5,000,000 in AD 117, and 4,400,00 in AD 390.  So the Roman Empire grew a lot after the late Republican periods.